# AngularJS - triggering a `visibility` not updating one time binding

Tags: angularjs

I am adding my datas as one time binding. and as well I am trying to updating the list of data too.

for trigger a update, I am trying to `toggling` the `ng-show` directive. But I am not getting the expected result. Might be I required to do all `CURD` operations with `one time bindng` - any one show the issue what i keep here or the correct way to do?

here is my code :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$timeout) {

  $scope.visible = true;
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.data = [
      {"name":"name1","city":"city1"},
      {"name":"name2","city":"city2"},
      {"name":"name3","city":"city3"}
      ]

  $scope.addItem = function( item ){

    $scope.visible = false;

    var value = Math.ceil(Math.random()*10+1);
    $scope.data.push({
      name:"name"+value,
      city:"city"+value
    });

    console.log( $scope.data );

    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.visible = true;
    });

  }
});
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/OC8ZHGwfmYbUaJ2Scslt?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

Use ng-if with your ng-show.
While ng-if detach dom element when false, ng-show just hide the element.

Comment: It works fine, I am finding small flickering how to avoid that?

Comment: Always when ng-if is false you detach the html element and when is true you attach they back.
Why can't you the normal ng-repeat data binding?

Comment: This is I show just a small piece from my hole data. I have 120 columns and each have multiple CURD process. I am finding Performance issue, that's the reason I do `one time` binding.

Comment: Try use `one time binding` in element instead of ng-repeat. Eg:

`<li ng-repeat="d in data">{{::d.name}}</li>`.

Maybe will be enough for your perfomance issue.